# Oracle Collection function - Not getting expected results

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, plsql

Please have a look at the below code. The 4th element in the collection is null, and hence I am expecting that the variable does not exists. But still, I am getting TRUE when using **exist** function. Please clarify as to why this is happening?

`DECLARE
  type nt is varray(5) of varchar2(5);
  nt1 nt := nt();
BEGIN
  nt1.extend(5);
  nt1 :=nt('ant','ball','cat',null,'elm');
  for i in nt1.first..nt1.last
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line(nt1(i));
    end loop;
  if nt1.exists(4) then dbms_output.put_line('TRUE'); end if;
END;`

Is it enough, If I have just extended that variable, for the exist function to evaluate to true?

Comment: `DECLARE
  type nt is varray(5) of varchar2(5);
  nt1 nt := nt();
BEGIN
  nt1.extend(3);
  nt1 :=nt('ant','ball','cat');--,null,'elm');
  for i in nt1.first..nt1.last
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line(nt1(i));
    end loop;
  if 
    nt1.exists(4) then dbms_output.put_line('TRUE'); 
    else dbms_output.put_line('FALSE'); 
  end if;
END;
  `

This code evaluates to FALSE, because I still have not extended that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is there, only its value is null.

With

```
nt1.extend(5);
```

you already create 5 entries, so `nt1.exists(4)` is true. As a varray can have no gaps, `exists` only tells you if the array is filled up to that position, yet. (And if it is, you can safely access that element.)

```
if nt1.exists(4) then 
  if nt1(4) is null then
    dbms_output.put_line('Entry 4 is empty (null)');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Entry 4 has value' || nt1(4));
  end if;
else
  dbms_output.put_line('Array not filled up till 4th element, yet');
end if;
```